# Performsegue within tableviewcell not working

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, segue, swift5

I have a tableview within my view controller and I'm having an issue performing a push segue when I click on my custom tableview cell. Is there something unique that I have to do when my tableview is within a view controller? Code below.

```
extension MyPersonalViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showGuest", sender: self)
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showGuest" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let guestVC = segue.destination as! GuestViewController
            guestVC.navigationItem.title = "Project"  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It shows showGuest everywhere.

Comment: "not working" means that it's not pushing to the next view? Are you sure that the identifier is "showGuest"?

Answer (score 0):

```
#You can try the below code:#

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SegueIdentifierName" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! DestinationViewController
            destinationVC.Outlet = "label"  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard you should be able to create a segue by holding the control key, then clicking on the cell, then dragging to the destination view controller.

In your `didSelectRowAt` method you don't need to do anything. By that I mean you don't need to call `performSegue`. All of that will happen under the hood thanks to the segue you defined in the storyboard.

In your `prepare` method you'll need to do something like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "showGuest" else { return }
    guard let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell else { return }
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
    guard let dest = segue.destination as? GuestViewController else { return }
    dest.data = data[indexPath.row]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Embed the view your table-cell is in, into a UINavgationController.

Instantiate your view

```
 let guestVC = segue.destination as! GuestViewController
 guestVC.navigationItem.title = "Project"  

 self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(guestVC!, animated: true)
```